# Amplitude of a wave, and boundary effects

Tags: waves, conservation-laws, boundary-conditions, string, density

[image]

[image]

I am curious as to what causes a discrepancy in the amplitude between the **incident** and the **reflected**/**transmitted** pulse. (* For instance, in the first image, the incident pulse seems to be of greater amplitude than the reflected pulse, but of equal (?) amplitude to the transmitted pulse). I am supposing this is an energy argument.

In addition, does the reflected pulse have equal width to the incident pulse, since the it is the same medium?

Answer (score 0):

I would say this happens because energy can't be destroyed, remember that for all waves amplitude is proportional to energy. So if the wave travelling through the more dense medium reflects with the same amplitude, and on top of that creates another wave in the less dense medium, then that would just create energy out of thin air.

P.S. Perhaps this question didn't receive enough traction because of the title, try phrasing it as a question since that fits what most people search for here and attracts more clicks.

Comment: Energy is related to the amplitude, but the proportion coefficient depends on the medium itself. There is more energy in the same amplitude for a denser medium. For example, one can show that if a sound wave travels from a spring to air the wave in the air will be twice the amplitude of the original wave, this doesn't contradict energy conservation because of the really small mass of air per unit length (meaning stuff move a lot but there is almost no stuff)

Answer (score 0):

To answer the second part of you your question:  No the reflected and transmitted pulses will not have the same width.

Waves travel more slowly in the denser medium.  The time taken for the wave to cross the boundary is the same as the time it takes to generate the reflected pulse.  During that time the pulse in the less dense medium will move farther that the pulse in the denser medium so it will be wider.